Power to shop from house service
I have 200A service to my house on two 100A breakers feeding two small fuse panels. I would like to run 100A service to a shop 60 feet underground from my main service breakers. Is it feasible to put my house on one of the 100A amp breakers and my shop on the other?
Also, I have been told by a professional contractor to run 2/2/2 with #6 ground but a friend with the local electric company suggests running 2/0 because I have a 240V compressor and a large 240V welder. He said since it’s underground cable, it's better to run larger wire with my equipment in the shop.

You want to do a load calculation(found online) to see how much power you use for the house first. A larger all electric house might be close to max, while a smaller house running mainly on gas should have plenty of left over power. Running the wire in conduit will make future repairs/upgrades on the line easier(no digging up again).

Posting a picture of the service panel would help us provide relevant answers. Pic's are added by selecting "edit" below your question, then selecting mountain icon.

@JonCuster OP's text is ambiguous. Since 100A breakers don't come as single 120V, only double 240V, I took it to mean: 2 x 100A double-breaker, each 100A double-breaker feeding a separate subpanel. But we need pictures to know for sure.

What size is the wire coming out of your 100A breakers?

2-2-2-6 aluminum is NOT legal for 100A. People who say that are reading the wrong table / ignoring 110.14(C) and text of 310.12.  Need 1 AWG AL for that.

2/0 AL burial quadraplex runs about a buck a foot more than #2, and where you need conduit 2" PVC conduit is another $1/ft more than 1.25", fittings and conduit bodies scale similarly.
What so you get for that? I think mostly just good relations from your friend who is advising outside of the scope of his professional qualifications. I would rely heavily on "budget" when justifying the smaller wire to your friend and go with the advice of the contractor who knows what limitations he's working with to be able to get a permit.
The contractor probably calculated that 90A@240v is going to be plenty of power for your welder and compressor, and the local contractor is quite likely aware that he may have a hard time creating a "load calc" that would show you have existing capacity to benefit from 135a 2/0 wire. A "load calc" may reveal you don't even have capacity for 90A, but usually feeders smaller than #2 AL actually cost more.

Upstream load calc limits wire size?  You can't overprovision an underground feed for unknown future use?  $100 or so for the greater capacity seems worth doing if trenching etc.

Didn't say a load calc would prevent the ability to use larger wire, just that there may be no benefit if your load calc won't allow a larger breaker feeding it.
